# How disable option with javascript?

Tags: javascript

in my project :

[image]

If I choose "Heures supp", I would like that in my second select/option, the "Du xx au xx" option is disable, and the "La journée" option is selected.

With my actual code :

```
var valeur = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
```

I can determine my first selected option.
And I want in a if condition, test it, to disable "Du xx au xx" option if my first selected option is "Heure supp".

```
<select class="browser-default custom-select" name="choiceUser" id="choiceUser" onchange="choiceDay2(this)">
    <option value="" disabled="" selected="">Choisissez la durée de l'absence</option>
    <option value="jour">La journée</option>
    <option value="periode">Du xx au xx</option>
</select>
```

I tried this but doesn't work, I'm not good in Javascript :

```
if (valeur == "Heures supp") {
        choiceDay = document.querySelector('[name="choiceUser"][option="periode"]');
        choiceDay.setAttribute('disabled', true);
}
```

EDIT:

I resolved the first problem : disable "periode" option :

```
choiceDay = document.querySelector('[name="choiceUser"]');
                periode = choiceDay.querySelector('option[value="periode"]');
                periode.setAttribute('disabled', true);
```

Now, I have to select the "Du xx au xx" option

Comment: There is no element with an `option` attribute equal to `"periode"`. There *is* an `option` *element* with a `value` attribute equal to `"periode"`...

Comment: I don't know what it is sorry ! But finally, I resolved the first time of my problem ! I will update my post !

Comment: If you've got an answer to your question, use the "Your Answer" section below, rather than updating your question.

Comment: _“I resolved the first problem : disable "periode" option […] Now, I have to select the "Du xx au xx" option”_ - the option with the text content `Du xx au xx` _is_ the option with the value `periode` that you just disabled, at least according to your HTML. What sense would it make to try and select that now …?

Comment: Isn't the option view the value "periode" the "Du xx au xx" option?

Comment: Heretic Monkey, yes, it is

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the problem :

Just make this :

```
var valeur = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
console.log(valeur);
if (valeur == "Heures supp") {
  choiceDay = document.querySelector('[name="choiceUser"]');
  periode = choiceDay.querySelector('option[value="periode"]');
  periode.setAttribute('disabled', true);

  journee = choiceDay.querySelector('option[value="jour"]');
  journee.setAttribute('selected', true);
  console.log(choiceDay);
}
```

Now, if in the first list, I select "Heure supp", then in the second list, the option "Du xx au xx" will be disabled. And by default, the option "journee" will be activated!

Thank you all!